# How can I add an element to my dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a **dimensional array**, and I would like to add an element in my lessons array

this is my array

```
$array = [
    [
      'id' => 1,
      'lessons' => [
         [
           'name' => 'PHP',
         ],
         [
           'name' => 'Python',
         ]
     ]
   ],
   [
      'id' => 1,
      'lessons' => [
         [
           'name' => 'Java',
         ],
         [
           'name' => 'Ruby',
         ]
     ]
   ],
];
```

I would like to add **flag** element to my **lessons**,

Desired output:

```
$array = [
        'id' => 1,
        'lessons' => [
           [
             'name' => 'PHP',
             'flag' => true
           ],
           [
             'name' => 'Python',
             'flag' => true
           ]
       ]
    ];
```

I would like to do that without a **nested foreach** or a **foreach**.  I tried with **array_map**

Code I tried :

```
$csmap_data = array_map(function($array){
    return $topics['lessons'] + ['flag' => true];
}, $topics);
```

Comment: Judging from your comments (below), it seems you might benefit from reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_%28data_structure%29).  A `dimensional array` as you call it, does not at all help the volunteers trying to help you! All arrays are _dimensional_, one-dimensional, multidimensional(two, three... etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array['lessons'] = array_map(function($lesson) {
    $lesson['flag'] = true;
    return $lesson;
}, $array['lessons']);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: its a dimensional array bro

Comment: Yeah, I get. But I don't seems to understand what you meant. The solution doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $array['lessons'] as $lesson )
{
   $lesson['flag'] = true;
}
```

Comment: its a dimensional array bro

Comment: does it product the desired output?